# Prettier rule "no-multiple-empty-lines" not working in React.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier

I want to have an ability to use 2 blank lines in some parts of my code. 
Prettier default behaviour allows to have 1 blank line maximum.

I've tried to use `"no-multiple-empty-lines": [2, {"max": 2 }]` but it doesn't work at all and prettier still complains.

This is my `.eslintrc` config file. If you need any other information please let me know.

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "commonjs": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [2, {"max": 2 }],
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": [2],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "prettier",
    "react"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect" // React version. "detect" automatically picks the version you have installed.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Same problem here, except its with airbnb style, not prettier.

Answer (score 3):

This might not work in your case -- I'm just running eslint without prettier -- but try this line instead:

```
"no-multiple-empty-lines": ["error", { "max": 2, "maxBOF": 0, "maxEOF": 0 }]
```

If you definitely want to run it through prettier with eslint though, it looks like that might not work at all. Not sure I'm reading [this issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint/issues/176) correctly, but it seems like that might not be configurable in prettier? If all you want is to change eslint's behavior though, I think the above line should work because I just had to use it in my own config.